# How to use the audio module (SFML-Linux )

Tags: c++, linux, audio, sfml

I am currently making a video game for school under Arch-linux (Manjaro) with SFML 2.5.1.

But I have an audio problem with the SFML.

I would like to integrate background music into my game in .ogg format (for more compatibility), but when I create an sf :: Music object or load this one, I get the message: "Failed to open the audio device ".

I am attaching screens of my configuration to this message for more details.

I use minimal code to reduce external problems.

If anyone has an idea, that would help me a lot.

Thanks.

**Code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sf::Music music;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        window.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I don't have an error message, just the message in the debug console and this message in my build log:

> -------------- Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
> Target is up to date.
> Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).

> -------------- Run: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
> Checking for existence: /home/damien/Bureau/dev_jv/Test/bin/Debug/Test
> Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/home/damien/Bureau/dev_jv/Test/lib/SFML-2.5.1/lib:
> Executing: termite -t Test -e " /app/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:.:/home/damien/Bureau/dev_jv/Test/lib/SFML-2.5.1/lib /home/damien/Bureau/dev_jv/Test/bin/Debug/Test  (in /home/damien/Bureau/dev_jv/Test/.)

[Minimal code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/latOb.png)

[Linker settings -> Link libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqqpt.png)

[Search directories -> Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT45H.png)

[Search directories -> Linker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFI1Z.png)

[SFML downloaded -> Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xkmV.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show all code, compile/link commands, error messages etc. as correctly formatted text.  Does the `Failed to open the audio device` message mention the device path?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have no other message outside of the debug console.
I don't use compile commands, i use the button build and run in codeblocks application.

The path to the device is not mentioned.

Sorry for the langage, my English is not perfect.

Comment: In the example above you dont even load Music, so I'm guessing it must be the problem with the drivers. If you dont have a speaker on your computer it'll be a bit hard to play audio.